# How to get the mapping relation between xbrl tag and name shown in financial statement?

Tags: tags, xbrl

The name shown in financial statement and xbrl tag name are different,take apple's 2019 financial statement as example.

[apple 2019 financial statement](https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/aapl-20200926.htm)

Click `sections--financial statement--consolidated statements of operations` and move mouse at the `274,515` ,
[image]

You can see

```
Tag 
us-gaap:RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax
Fact    
274,515,000,000
```

The tag name is `RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax` in xbrl term, it is called as `Total net sales`, maybe there exists a table mapping every xbrl tag name with name shown on financial statements,where can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a mapping between tag names (they are called concepts) and user-readable English names (they are called labels) in what is called the label linkbase.

You can click on the right arrow in the pop-up window that can be seen on your screenshot, which will display all the associated labels.

[image]

However, there is no guarantee that these labels match exactly what is seen on the HTML page, because this is Inline XBRL and the text surrounding the tagged data is completely free, as opposed to the tabular view an XBRL processor would automatically reconstruct from the taxonomy attached to the report. Ideally, the filings should be created in a way that the two should match, though.

In this case, "Total net sales" would be a Total label (i.e., used when the data is displayed in context as a total), but it does not seem that this label appears in the label linkbase here, at least as shown in the window.

Regarding a large, flat, tabular representation of the entire label linkbase of a filing: I did not manage to find it for this specific (version of the) viewer, however there are many XBRL processors that do offer this (e.g., export to CSV or Excel).